# Laravel file validation when creating vs editing

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form to create a Product. The product has two images. The first image is required. When I create a Product I set the validation rule required for the first image. I dont know what to do when editing the product. How can I validate it? Because if the request hasnt the file maybe it was already uploaded when the Product was created so it shouldnt return errors. How should I handle this case? Im looking for the cleanest and laravel way.

Comment: You would have your controller make a call to check if the product already has an image, then conditionally display an error. If you post the code you are currently using, I/we can suggest how to modify it to incorporate this change

Comment: Make separate rules for creating and editing the product. You can see an example of it [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/laravel-5-validation-request-how-to-handle-validation-on-update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While editing product, you can remove rule on base of product id

In your own Requests class

```
 /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules() {
        $rules = [
            'title' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
        ];
        if (!($this->request->get('product_id'))) {
            $rules['product_image'] = 'required';
        }
        return $rules;
    }
```